# Help with a difficult limit involving number e

Tags: limits, exponential-function, central-limit-theorem

I was studying a proof of the Central Limit Theorem (for iid variables), and at some step, the proof requires me to find the limit of 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1-\frac{t^2}{2n}+o(\frac{t^2}{n}) \right)^n=e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \qquad(1)$$
where $o(x^k)$ is a function such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac {o(x^k)}{x^k}=0$ for any positive integer k (little-o notation).

I know that, by the definition of $e$, we have: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1-\frac{t^2}{2n} \right)^n=e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$$

Also, we can rearrange the terms in (1) to have a similar expression:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1-a\frac{t^2}{2n} \right)^n$$
With $a=1-2\frac{o(\frac{t^2}{n})}{\frac{t^2}{n}}$.

However, I don't know how to argue that this expression must converge to $e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$. In an intuitive level, it seems logical that this must be the limit, though I would want to have a more rigourous argument. How can I calculate this limit?

Comment: Use the fact that $\alpha^n=e^{n\ln\alpha}$, and find a development of $\ln(1-\frac{t^2}{2n}+o(\frac{t^2}{n}))$.

Comment: If I do that, at some step I have to use the L'Hopital's Rule to find the limit. I don't know exactly what expression should I get when I take the derivative of the little o(.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln(1+u)= u + o(u)$ when $u\to0$. So :
$$\ln\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2n}+o\left(\textstyle\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) = -\frac{t^2}{2n}+o\left(\textstyle\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
and
$$\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2n}+o\left(\textstyle\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^n = e^{n\ln\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)} = e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}+o(1)} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$$
$o(1)$ meaning some sequence with limit $0$.

Comment: I get the argument, but let me ask you a dumb question: why don't you include the remainder term in the first equation?

Comment: Which one ? The development $\ln(1+u)=u+o(u)$ ? It's a general formula, where I substitute your $-\frac{t^2}{2n}+o(1/n)$ in $u$... It **does** tend to zero when $n\to\infty$, no ?

Comment: I mean, what happened with $o(u)$. Shouldn't the expression be $u+o(u)=-t^2/2n + o(1/n) + o(-t^2/2n + o(1/n))$?

Comment: Yes, but $o(-t^2/2n+o(1/n))$ is simply $o(1/n)$.

Comment: Nice! That's what I was not understanding. Thank you.